# ArrayAdapter not updating with notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView that I populate with an ArrayList which works fine, but when I clear and repopulate the ArrayList with new items and call notifyDataSetChanged(), the getView() of the adapter is never called and the ListView doesn't reflect the new data. Not sure where I'm going wrong, but any help is appreciated! Thank you

initializing views and adapter

```
Arraylist<Movie> moviesArray = new Arraylist<>();
movieListView = view.findViewById(R.id.movie_list_view);
movieListAdapter = new MovieListArrayAdapter(this, requireContext(), R.layout.list_item, moviesArray);
movieListView.setAdapter(movieListAdapter);
```

call for new data

```
moviesArray.clear()
moviesViewModel.GetMovies();
```

observing results (My BottomSheet gets updated, so I know I'm receiving data)

```
moviesViewModel.getMoviesResult().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<MovieList>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(MovieList movieList) {
            if (movieList!=null) {
            moviesArray.addAll(movieList.getResults());
                    movieListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            UpdateBottomSheet(view, 0);
        }
    });
```

adapter (getView not called when list data is updated)

```
public class MovieListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

Fragment fragment;
List<Movie> movies;

public MovieListArrayAdapter(Fragment fragment, @NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Movie> movies) {
    super(context, resource, movies);
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.movies = movies;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    Movie movie = movies.get(position);
    Movie top_movie = movies.get(0);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView movie_imageview = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image);

    if (movie==top_movie) {
        convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(fragment.requireContext()).load(movie.getImage()).into(movie_imageview);
    } else {
        convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: What is `movieSwipeFlickAdapter` and do you mean to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on this?

Comment: Whoops, I made the names more basic for the post so they're easier to follow, and forgot to change that one. I just edited it, sorry. But yes, I call notifyDataSetChange() on the correct adapter

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the list in the adapter.

```
movieListAdapter.addAll(movieList.getResults());
movieListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I've tried this as well with the same result :/ what's weird is the adapter is getting the data because I called movieListAdapter.getItem(0).getTitle() after addAll() and notifyDataSetChanged() and the output is correct, but the getView() isn't being called to update the view